# Get a menu of windows that are open with command-` like you have with command-tab

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, application-switcher

This is one of my biggest frustrations on mac, Im thinking about disabling nested windows because of it- if thats even possible

When I *hold* command-tab I see a nice menu of the open apps I have. I can see the app Im going to switch to directly

Now if I want to switch between windows of the same app I just have command-` which sucks because I cant hold it to see a menu of windows that are open. If I've got 3+ windows of my IDE open this is shitty and frustrating because I have to cycle through until I get to the window I want. I cant, like I can with command-tab, see a menu and then go directly to the right window

Is there any 3rd tool that does this or a mac feature Im not familiar with?

Comment: thats almost what I want but I really like the behaviour of command-tab. just hitting the same thing to cycle one way and then shift to cycle back instead of hitting command-down and then using arrow keys. basically the same behaviour as command+` but with a menu like command-tab

Comment: There are 3rd party app switchers such as Contexts, SwitchGlass, and Witch. But I think Witch might be exactly what you are looking for. It replaces the macOS App Switcher and it understands Apps have multiple windows.

Answer (score 1):

See the **Mission Control** System Preference for options to display windows.

"Application Windows" shows you just the windows for that application. The default key is either <kbd>F4</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>down</kbd>.

Mission Control shows you all the windows in each Desktop Space, which you can select to be grouped together by application or not.

Comment: Or use tabs, then all the titles are visible.

Comment: ctrl+down is almost what I want. Is there a shortcut that works like command+tab where you hit it to cycle through apps? its a little wonky to hit ctrl+down and then use arrow keys- maybe im doing it wrong

Comment: You can click on the window you want. If you want to cycle through windows, then use Command backtick - but I thought you didn't want that!

Comment: I want command+` but with a menu like command+tab has. maybe there is a way to remap command+` to send ctrl+down first and then send left or right with shift to change?

Comment: Just keep pressing the right arrow to cycle through the windows.